# Specify path for android assets subfolder

Tags: android

I would like to know how to specify a string path for android assets sub folder.
For instance, I have a sub folder within the assets folder,
e.g: `Assets > Myname(Sub folder).`
How do I retrieve the String path for this sub folder?

The result I want: String path= `"Assets/MyName"`. I know it might use `AssetsManager` to retrieve it, but I not sure how to do it exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May this help you:

```
AssetManager aManager = appContext.getAssets();
String[] filelist = aManager.list("MyName");

for(String name:filelist){
     System.out.println(name);    
}
```

And if you want pass reference of a file then you can use
 `file:///android_assets/MyName/yourfilename`

Answer (score 0):

you can get path for Asset sub folder as below.

file://android_assets/MyName